# Erro no Azure: Não consigo carregar view a partir do controlador!

Tags: php, html, cloud, microsoft-azure

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de noticias desenvolvido em PHP(MVC) no qual cada url aciona um controlador que chama um view.

Porém no azure não é chamada a view correspondente enquanto no xampp/apache o sistema funciona perfeitamente.

Como configuro o acesso as view apartir do controlador dentro do azure ?

**codigo do web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^(.*)$" />
                     <conditions>
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                 </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

URL do sistema PHP em MVC: http://crudmvcphp.azurewebsites.net/

Repositório do código do sistema: https://github.com/alexjosesilva/CrudMVCPHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o framework PHP que você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando um framework puro. Com estrutura minima

Comment: https://github.com/alexjosesilva/CrudMVCPHP

Comment: Então, você já tentou abrir um issue no github sobre esse problema? Pode ser um problema no framework dada em consideração que suas configurações estão corretas.